What is the difference between Publishing types?
Under page settings > publication type > Discussion, blog post, idea - what is the difference between these three types? Is it only the template options that vary?

Are you using modern or classic pages? I don't see a property called "Publication type" in modern pages. This may be a custom column, not out of the box SharePoint.

To better help you with your problem, can you provide a screenshot?
